# Как правильно отформатировать дату?

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать строковое значение даты, созданное с помощью `new Date().getTime()`

> результат:1531223496095

Мне нужно преобразовать в обычное значение, например

> 12.06.2018 и указать часы и минуты

Answer (score 3):

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('ru'));
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638063/6677992

**UPD:**

> и указать часы и минуты

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleString('ru').substring(0,17));
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем делать через `new Date().getTime()`, если в итоге нужна все-равно дата?
Можно например так, или же второй вариант - обратно перевести в `Date`

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('ru'));

var d = new Date().getTime();
var d = new Date(d);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('ru', {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}));
```

Comment: Ну что бы сортировать потом

Comment: Не знаете как добавить еще часы и минуты?